# Issue with "set terminal png" Command with GNUPlot C++ (C++ 14, VS 22)

Tags: c++, gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I'm attempting to save a `GNUPlot` plot as a PNG file. I'm using C++ 14 and Visual Studio 2022.

I have the following minimal example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<float>> data = {};

    data.push_back(vector<float>{0, 0, 0});
    data.push_back(vector<float>{1, 1, 1});
    data.push_back(vector<float>{2, 2, 2});

    Gnuplot gp;

    gp << "set terminal png\n";
    gp << "set title 'test'\n";

    gp << "set dgrid3d 100,100\n";

    gp << "splot" << gp.file1d(data) << "with pm3d title 'test'" << endl;

    gp << "set output 'test.png'\n";
    gp << "replot\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I noticed a really peculiar issue whenever I try to run the example code above;

Any command that is sent immediately after the `set terminal png` appears to get the first few of its characters removed/corrupted... In the example above, the command `set title 'test'` is the command sent immediately after, and this is a warning that's presented by the program console whenever I run the code above:

```
gnuplot> t title 'test'
         ^
         line 0: invalid command
```

And my plot gets generated without the title `test`.

I can confirm that the `set terminal png` is the command that causes the issue, as if I add an additional `set title 'test'` command, the extra command gets read properly, and my plots gets generated with the `test` title.

I'm aware that the [`GNUPlot` C++ implementation](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream) is known for not being too friendly with Windows OS (which is what I'm building this on), and I was just wondering whether this was an issue encountered by someone else, or whether this is one of those Windows artifacts.

Thanks for reading my post, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You are using the library as prescribed, so it would be a bug in the library or gnuplot.

Comment: As a wid guess, have you tried `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`?